# Is there any way to mathematically prove whether |s'| is greater, equal or less than |s| in optics?

Tags: physics, axioms

I am studying a physics course in college and I found that it is actually really difficult to remember long-phrased statements. Thus, I have been trying to determine those statements through the use of logic and mathematical reasoning and the formulas that are given in the textbook.

This problem is a concave mirror exercise that does not have any number. In fact, it is only based on a diagram and abstract variables.

Some formulas have been given in the textbook. They are:
$$\frac 1f = \frac1s + \frac{1}{s'}$$

$$m = -\frac{s'}{ s}$$

$$2f = R$$
I have been told that all distances from the vertex made with the optic axis and a concave mirror are positive when going away from the mirror in the same side as the center of curvature of the mirror.

This is what I have done so far:

[My procedure so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gm25o.jpg)

With all of this, I can prove that the image is inverted and real. However, It is highly difficult for me to determine whether |s'| is greater, equal or less than |s|, which is necessary to determine whether |m| is greater, equal or less than 1.

Comment: The community appreciates your effort in providing context. +1. But it is not clear what the question is. You are requested to quote the question verbatim.

Comment: In a more specific way, I want to know if there is a way with the presented axioms and equations to determine whether the absolute value of m is greater, equal or less than 1 using only abstract variables.

Comment: I would challenge you to try and focus on remembering/understanding how to derive the formulas that you are memorizing. Once you have a feel for the methodology you won't need to memorize them anymore. Otherwise you'll forget them in 3-6 months. If you want to be able to truly say you understand the material you should know where those equations come from. Otherwise although you may know how to find an answer,  you will not know WHY it is the answer. You will just be blindly applying an algorithm you've memorized for how to solve a certain problem type.

Comment: The symmetry between $s$ and $s'$ says they are interchangeable, so one can be greater and one less as you wish depending on the application.  In fact one is greater than or equal to $2f$ and the other less than or equal to $2f$.  In lens applications, where images can be on either side of the lens there are more possibilities because one of $s, s'$ may be negative.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with real image, where $s$ and $s'$ are positive. And we should consider first the case $s'=s$. Then $$\frac1f=\frac2s$$or $s=2f$. So when the object is at the center of curvature, $R$ from the mirror, then the image is also formed at the same position. If you look now at the first equation, increasing $s$ will decrease $s'$. When $s\to \infty$, then $s'\to f$. If you decrease $s$, from $2f$ to $f$, then $s'$ will increase. Note now that at $s=f$, you get $\frac1{s'}=0$. This corresponds both to $s'=\infty$ and $s'=-\infty$.

Once $s<f$, then $\frac1s>\frac1f$. So $s'$ must be negative. So we rewrite the first equation as $$\frac1f=\frac1s-\frac1{|s'|}$$
Since $1/f>0$, then $$\frac1s>\frac1{|s'|}$$ or $$s<|s'|$$